# Iterar una List en Java

Tags: java, spring, lista

Cómo puedo iterar esta lista para obtener los nombres:

**Clase Tarjetas:**

```
   public class Tarjetas {


    private List<Tarjeta> tarjetas;

        public List<Tarjeta> getTarjetas() {
        return tarjetas;
    }

    public void setTarjetas(List<Tarjeta> tarjetas) {
        this.tarjetas = tarjetas;
    }


}
```

**Clase Tarjeta:**

```
public class Tarjeta {
    private String nombre;
    private String id;
    private String lista;
    private String idLista;


    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }
    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getLista() {
        return lista;
    }
    public void setLista(String lista) {
        this.lista = lista;
    }
    public String getIdLista() {
        return idLista;
    }
    public void setIdLista(String idLista) {
        this.idLista = idLista;
    }

}
```

Tengo este método que recibe un objeto json,

```
 @RequestMapping(value ="/j", method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public void posted(Tarjetas t) {
     System.out.println("Post "); 
     List<Tarjeta> tar=  t.getTarjetas();
     for ( int i=0; i<tar.size();i++){
         System.out.println("Nombre: "+ tar.get(i).getNombre());
     }
```

}

No consigo obtener los nombres, no se si estoy recorriendo bien la Lista

Comment: En este  caso me parece estas usando spring  , aporta mas datos para una respuesta precisa, que informacion entrega tu url + /j ???

Comment: Agrega un ejemplo del JSON que recibes

Answer (score 2):

la estas recorriendo de forma correcta, me parece que posiblemente no tienes en realidad datos la lista.

```
List<Tarjeta> tar=  t.getTarjetas();
     for ( int i=0; i<tar.size();i++){
         System.out.println("Nombre: "+ tar.get(i).getNombre());
     }
```

Debes usar el método `setTarjetas()` para introducir valores a la lista.

Answer (score 0):

creo que es como dice Jorgesys. Te falta 'setear' lo que vas a recorrer. Algo así, creo.

```
List<Tarjeta> tar= new ArrayList<>();
tar.setTarjetas(t);

for ( int i=0; i<tar.size();i++){
  System.out.println("Nombre: "+ tar.get(i).getNombre());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes recorrerla de la siguiente manera:

```
for (Tarjeta tarjeta : t.getTarjetas()){
    System.out.println("Nombre: "+ tarjeta.getNombre());
}
```

Pero creo que el problema es que tu lista de tarjeta viene vacía, puedes facilitar el JSON recibido para ver si lo estas enviando correctamente.